# Creating directory tree recursively

Tags: c#, sql, recursion, directory

I have a directory tree in my sql database which i created/uploaded from a directory on my hard drive.

Now i want to reverse this and donwload it back to my pc.

The problem is that i do not know how to do this recursively.

My plan until now is:

Getting directoryname(from combobox where i choose which directory to download) and create directory.
Find subdirectorys (manage via PK and Parent_ID) (because there can be more subfolders in a folder) sort them by alphabet. Create directory on pc under the root directory (replicate the directory tree from original) and search if this one hast subdirectorys. If it does not, then got next in the alphabet, create a directory and check if it has subfolders. If it has subfolders, sort them, go to the first one, create directory on pc, check if it has subdirectorys and so on and so on.

I hope i could make it clear what i had in mind. But because there is the possibility of almost infinite combinations and interlacing i will have to program this recursively but i sadly am out of creativity :/

I hope some of you can help me out and give me an idea how to tackle this.

This is currently the code i wrote, until the first recursion:

```
//creating of the root directory on the pc
string rootname = ComboboxRoots.SelectedItem.ToString();
string rootdirectory = TextboxDestination.Text + "\\" + rootname;
Methods.CreateDir(rootdirectory);

//searching for subfolders in sql database, if there are several sort them alphabetically in an array
int? rootPK = Methods.getFolderPK(rootname);
int pk_dirRoot;
pk_dirRoot = rootPK ?? default(int);
string [] dirname = Methods.GetDirname("SELECT dirname FROM  FolderUpload_Directorys WHERE parent_id = @rootpk", pk_dirRoot);
string sortedDirnames = "";
if(dirname.Length > 1){
    Array.Sort(dirname);
    for(int a = 0; a < dirname.Length; a++){
        if(dirname[a] != null){
            sortedDirnames = sortedDirnames + "/" + dirname[a];
        }                   
    }           
}

string[] DirnamesTokens = sortedDirnames.Split('/');
//going through sorted array
//with each entry,create directory on pc and see if there are subfolders, if multiple, sort them, create directory for first entry, check if it has subfolders......
for(int a  = 0; a < DirnamesTokens.Length; a++){

}
```

**EDIT:**

I use SQL Server, with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

And these are my methods used:

To get the PrimaryKey of a specific Foldername:

```
public static int? getFolderPK(string dirname)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EVOPC18\XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=True; Trusted_Connection = True"))
    using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandText = @"
    SELECT pk_dir
    FROM   FolderUpload_Directorys
    WHERE  dirname = @dirname";
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dirname", dirname);
        cn.Open();
        return cm.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
    }
}
```

And getting the Directory name for a specific PK of the parent_id:

```
public static string[] GetDirname(string Command, int rootpk)
{
    string [] dirnames =  new string [100];
    int a = 0;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EVOPC18\XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=True; Trusted_Connection = True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Command, connection))

    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rootpk", rootpk);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dirnames[a] = reader["dirname"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return dirnames;
}
```

And this is the DB:

[image]

Comment: [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) will create all the directories in the path that do not exist.

Comment: @juharr wouldnt i sill need to create every branch? because i would not help me creating only the deepest, because certain branching directories would be missing

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide sample data as DDL+DML as well as add the tag for the relevant RDBMS you are using (product tag and version tag). As Juharr wrote - the `CreateDirectory` method will create all the directories in the path that doesn't exists.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry i'm rather new to that so i have do idea what ddl, dml or rdbms are. Oke i googled it and i will add

Comment: DDL - Data Definition language - i.e create table statements. DML - data manipulation language - i.e insert into statements. RDBMS - relational database management system - i.e MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Updated

Comment: [Use a recursive CTE to build the paths from your table data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955335/sql-server-recursive-self-join/42955558#42955558) Then all you need to to create the different paths.